# Build an alphabetised polyglot

Tags: string, kolmogorov-complexity, polyglot, rosetta-stone

As [TIO can show](https://tio.run/#), every letter of the Latin alphabet is represented when it comes to languages. For every letter there is at least 1 programming language whose name begins with that letter. Your task is to create a polyglot in order to demonstrate that.

Your program should be runnable in between 2 and 26 different languages, each of which starts with a different letter. However, if your program runs in \$N\$ languages, the languages used must have the first \$N\$ letters of the alphabet as the first letter of their names. So if your program runs in 5 languages, the languages must start with `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`. (e.g. [A Pear Tree](https://tio.run/#a-pear-tree), [BrainSpace](https://tio.run/#brainspace), [C++](https://tio.run/#cpp-gcc), [Dash](https://tio.run/#dash) and [Enlist](https://tio.run/#enlist))

Your program should take no input, and output a constant string: the alphabet (case-irrelevant, in order), but with the letter of the language name removed. So the language beginning with `A` should output `BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` (or the equivalent lower case version). Case doesn’t have to be consistent for different languages, but it does between runs in the same language.

Any languages are fair game, so long as no letters are repeated. This rules out using different versions for most languages (e.g. Python 2 vs Python 3), but this is only as a consequence of having unique letters. Seriously and Actually, for example, are considered different versions, but can both be used in the same answer as they start with different characters.

If using languages with custom code pages, then, as is standard, the bytes must match between programs, not characters.

Submissions are scored by number of languages used, with a tie breaker of shortest code.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19215/66833) (deleted). Please don't hesitate to leave any feedback.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing an answer that includes a language beginning with Z.

Comment: @Adám I'm tempted to offer a bounty to any valid answer that includes [Ziim](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6945/66833)

Comment: Are separators between letters allowed?

Comment: @DomHastings As long as they are consistent (only within one language, different languages may use different separators), and not letters themselves, yes

Comment: Looking forward to a polyglot with ABC, bc, and C

Comment: I’d like to see a Python and Whitespace answer

Comment: It would be interesting to see a (mostly) shell-only answer, as there are ash, bash, csh, dash, [eshell](https://www.ubuntupit.com/linux-shell-roundup-15-most-popular-open-source-linux-shells/), fish, Hamilton shell, Ion, Korn, mksh, Oh, posh, rc, sh, tcsh, xonsh, yash, zsh... Missing are G, J, L, N, Q, U, V, W.

Comment: Thanks for the generous bounty @Bubbler! I've looked at adding mksh too in return!

Comment: Another fun fact: The entire A-Z range is covered by [brainfuck derivatives](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Brainfuck_derivatives). Even [trivial brainfuck equivalents](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Brainfuck_equivalents) have most of them (missing DJNQXY).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell), [evil](https://web.archive.org/web/20070103000858/www1.pacific.edu/%7Etwrensch/evil/index.html), [fish](https://fishshell.com/), [goruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/extension_rdoc.html#label-goruby+Interpreter+Implementation), [Haystack](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack), [Implicit](https://github.com/aaronryank/Implicit), [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), [ksh](http://www.kornshell.com/), [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), [mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm), [Numberwang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Numberwang_(brainfuck_derivative)), [OSH](https://www.oilshell.org/), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), [Super Stack!](https://github.com/TryItOnline/superstack), [Taco](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacO), [Unefunge-98 (Pyfunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), [V (Vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), [xonsh](https://xon.sh/), [yash](https://yash.osdn.jp), [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 1009 bytes

9 shells, 3 Rubies, some 2D (and 1D!) languages and many languages I learned just for this challenge. I really enjoyed this challenge and learned some new languages and features. I enjoyed finding a shorter way than just the raw string in some languages (in some languages generating the string seemed longer) and trying to re-use the `s` variable as many times as possible was fun too. I've also tried to keep the byte-count as low as possible. If I find the time and the inclination, I wonder if I could start adding the letters of the alphabet to the end instead... Crazy talk...

```
' # "194940711909711999999999999940391270919999999999994039127zaeeeawawawawavaeeaaaaamvawvusb"' #165#1#1;.040;"ZYXWVTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"8 3*k,q"ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"o¡72"8:é9:é8++:90+1®;65µ
'\&p"A""K"R"M""Z"R&o;';#   x%"ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"x.-$"BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 0 65 65 if pop dup dup 83 sub if pop outputascii 0 fi pop 1 add dup 91 sub fi "ZYXVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"#25&o   @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ"
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'
0//1;
try:echo -n;print(s[0:23]+"YZ");
except:print(s[0:15]+s[16:]);"""/.__id__;begin ~:*;puts s.gsub ?J,"";rescue;begin A;puts s.gsub ?G,"";rescue;puts s.gsub ?R,"";end;end;'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;';/
('Q'⎕R'')⎕A⋄'\} #<esc>ggdG¬AZ:s/#\|V//"""#\'⍵
```

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots)

The relevant code is:

```
.-$"BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

This needs to be wrapped in `[`...`]` to avoid [Extended Brainfuck Type I] from outputting rubbish before the desired string because of the `.`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdcppAFMfveYozC5UkRmH9irBNW8yHJsZoNDGJ4hAixDKdinUhsanmqned9q4P0MvOdHqXF7BvkhexC9FWZ1hYmD3nd/7nA0zadRzL9ehsJgIPCCsZJSNvYazISvBcXhk5reDUlqzgCOu9adu2eTe/btnJDNb7W/Pu1qfXiKnjXJbHPCZJOSMT1Lq8OG@eNuontepx5ah8eFAq7u/t7hQ0lIf0xrvND0gr7Ozu7RcPDstHleNq7aTeOD1rnl9ctpA7/bGVQnn1z0@F7Xw8ripyHE9/k1x2@siJemyANITKqI4qCLVQPeYSkfAAMHrBVAPRUoTqKJkQ0HPOKDfIkMsGt3MDA3cAlv@882mg/vXC6vrewPfMYKws4MYJjRhMywphBYcwswcDaJ5FDoBPZWMuq/bNYgTL5cyr4eh2lHdRLJF5kZMlCRPOG35U7e5bFxJ9Mhg6fW@NtmU1le7EEQPXCWePuvbAU//7cLYTp22cUzvrBCEkJQ3DsQyDXNs9pw8P6gZhLVKgyV7Qy@vDTYTI0KZd354j2ipQXAJWHPXAYfetcItcGxL3IFDoxGJhwWF/Ue0x/8jxSAhdtVmIZ3o@hW026EWsLnyiUkuazNE26DZsP4C9Clz@A/QwuS4kQF9KH0B8UMZ/nZAqaI1S7WB3VawsrVCCUW1WjJp2WoLOeBxiAh17Q0hYUI1EwlDm6INw1tirG0GClQwVaTJXCo8FaXLFfmyJWxNPxKdv3@uiuM5e2tOXz6I@Af4lG/mrXs8qTn9pLZVKvD5uShL7orwuPn19nM3@Ag)

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

The relevant code is:

```sh
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'...'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;'...' #
```

This first line sets `$s` to be the full alphabet in uppercase, so `-z  $s` is false and skipped over. `$status` is unset, `\e` is treated as an escape, not a `\` and `e`, `$BASHPID` is set, `$_OVM_PATH` is not and `$USER_ID` isn't set so `B` is replaced with the empty string in `$s` (`${s/B/}`) and `echo`ed it out.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg4FEzHQKlE2UWvCqd532rg/Qy850eucL0DfxRegmQoWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fSdukN7OZCDwgrKSUlLyFsSIr/nN5peSkghNbsoJDrPembdvm3fy6ZSfTXx9uzbtbj7YRU8eZNI95TOJySiaofnlxXjut6ieV8nHpqHh4UMjv7@3u5DSUheTG@82PSMvt7O7t5w8Oi0el43LlRK@entXOLy7rqD/9uZVAWfXvL4XtbDSqKnIUT/@QTHr6yIlGZIA0hIpIRyWE6kiP9IlIeAAYvWKqvmghRHUUjwnoOWeYG2TIpP3buYZBfwCW97yzSaBee2Hte@7Ac03acRwWcO0ERgymZQWwggOY2f0B1M5CB8An0pE@q/bdYgTL5cyr4eh2mHdRLJF5kZMlCRPOHX5S7c5NH2I9Mhg6PXeNNmQ1kWxGEQPXCWePOvbAVV98ON2M0gbOqM11ghCS4q2WY7VapG13nR48qBuEtUiBxrt@L28PNxEiQ5t2PHuOaKtAfglYcei@w@5ZwRa5BsTuQaDQjESCgoP@wtpj/pHjkgC6arAQ13Q9Ctts0ItYQ/hMpbo0maMNMGzYfgB7Fbj8DxhBckOIgbGU3od4v4wXnYDKadVC5WB3VaworVBCq1wrtSraaQGa43GACXTsDiFmQTkUCUKZowfCWXVPb/kJVjKUpMlcKTjmpMkV@7Elbk08EZ@@/9BFcZ29tKevX0RjAvxrNvI33a6Vn/7W6iqVeGNckyT2RXlDfPr2OJv9Aw)

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal)

The relevant code is:

```
x%"ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"x
```

The cursors spawn from the `%` and are terminated by the `x`s. This needed to be moved slightly to prevent additional output.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg4FEmmkLlE2UWvCqd532rg/Qy850eucL0DfxRegmQoWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fScccWk7PfD@bicADwkpKSclbGCuy4j@XV0pOKjixJSs4xHpn2rZt3s6vG3Yy/fXhxry98WgbMXWcSfOYxyQup2SC6pcX57XTqn5SKR@XjoqHB4X8/t7uTk5DWUhuvNv8iLTczu7efv7gsHhUOi5XTvTq6Vnt/OKyjvrTn1sJlFX//lLYzkajqiJH8fQPyaSnD5xoRAZIQ6iIdFRCqI70SJ@IhAeA0Qum6osWQlRH8ZiAnnKGuUGGTNq/nWsY9AdgeU87mwTqtRfWvucOPNekHcdhAddOYMRgWlYAKziAmd0fQO0sdAB8Ih3ps2rfLEawXM68Go5uh3kXxRKZFzlZkjDh3OEn1e687UOsRwZDp@eu0YasJpLNKGLgOuHsUcceuOqzD6ebUdrAGbW5ThBCUrzVcqxWi7TtrtODe3WDsBYp0HjX7@X14SZCZGjTjmfPEW0VyC8BKw7dd9g9K9gi14DYHQgUmpFIUHDQX1h7zD9yXBJAVw0W4pquR2GbDXoRawifqVSXJnO0AYYN2/dgrwKX/wEjSG4IMTCW0vsQ75fxrBNQOa1aqBzsrooVpRVKaJVrpVZFOy1AczwOMIGO3SHELCiHIkEoc/RAOKvu6S0/wUqGkjSZKwXHnDS5Yj@2xK2JJ@Lj9x@6KK6zl/b49YtoTIB/yUb@qtu18tPfWl2lEm@Ma5LEvihviI/fHmazfw)

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell)

The relevant code is:

```sh
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'...'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;'...' #
```

As per Bash, this first sets `$s` to be the full alphabet in uppercase. so `-z $s` is false. `$status` is empty, `\e` is an escape sequence and doesn't match `e`, but `$-` is empty in Dash so that conditional is met and we `echo` out `ABC` followed by `$s` with the prefix `ABCD` removed (`${s#ABCD}`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIEwOJmOkUKBuUWvCqd532rg/Qy850eucL0DfxRegmQoWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fiW3Rm9lMBB4QVlJKSt7CWJEV/7m8UnJSwYktWcEh1nvLcRzrbn7dspPlrw@31t3tkLYQU8eZNI95TOJySiaofnlxXjut6ieV8nHpqHh4UMjv7@3u5DSUheTG@82PSMvt7O7t5w8Oi0el43LlRK@entXOLy7rqDf9uZVAWfXvL4XtbDSqKnIUT/@QTHr6yIlGpI80hIpIRyWE6kiP9IhIeAAYvWKqvmghRHUUjwnoOWeYG2TIpP3bvYZ@rw/28Hlnk0CHrYW1N/T6Q8@ibddlAdduYMRg2XYAKziAmd0fQO0sdAB8Ih3psWrfLUawXM68Go5uh3kXxRKZFzlZkjDhvMEn1Wnf9CDWJf2B2/XWaENWE8lmFDFwnXDOqO30PfXFh9PNKG3gjNpcJwghKW6arm2apOV03C48qBuEtUiBxjt@L28PNxEiA4e2h84c0VaB/BKw4tB9h9O1gy1yDYjdg0ChGYkEBQf9hbXH/CPXIwF01WAhnuUNKWyzQS9iDeEzlerSZI42wHBg@wGcVeDyP2AEyQ0hBsZSeh/i/TJedAIqp1ULlYPdVbGitEIJZrlWMivaaQGa43GACXTsDSBmQzkUCUKZowvCWXVPN/0EKxlK0mSuFBxz0uSK/dgStyaeiE/ff@iiuM5e2tPXL6IxAf41G/mbTsfOT39rdZVKvDGuSRL7orwhPn17nM3@AQ)

## [evil](https://web.archive.org/web/20070103000858/www1.pacific.edu/%7Etwrensch/evil/index.html)

The relevant code is:

```
zaeeeawawawawavaeeaaaaamvawvusb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg5FEmmkLlE2QWvCqd532rg/Qy850eucL0DfxRegmQoWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fiT103s9mIvCAsJJSUvIWxoqs@M/llZKTCk5syQoOsd6Ztm2bt/NryE6mvz4MzduhR68RU8eZNI95TOJySiaofnlxXjut6ieV8nHpqHh4UMjv7@3u5DSUheTGu82PSMvt7O7t5w8Oi0el43LlRK@entXOLy7rqDf9uZVAWfXvL4XtbDSqKnIUT/@QTHr6wIlGpI80hIpIRyWE6kiP9IhIeAAYvWCqvmghRHUUjwnoKWeYG2TIpP3buYF@rw@W97SzSaDe9cLa89y@55q07Tgs4MYJjBhMywpgBQcws/sDqJ2FDoBPpCM9Vu2bxQiWy5lXw9HtMO@iWCLzIidLEiacO/ik2u23PYh1SX/gdN012pDVRLIZRQxcJ5w9att9V3324XQzShs4ozbXCUJIirdajtVqkWu743ThXt0grEUKNN7xe3l9uIkQGdi07dlzRFsF8kvAikP3HXbXCrbINSB2BwKFZiQSFBz0F9Ye848clwTQVYOFuKbrUdhmg17EGsJnKtWlyRxtgGHD9j3Yq8Dlf8AIkhtCDIyl9D7E@2U86wRUTqsWKge7q2JFaYUSWuVaqVXRTgvQHI8DTKBjdwAxC8qhSBDKHF0Qzqp7estPsJKhJE3mSsExJ02u2I8tcWviifj4/YcuiuvspT1@/SIaE@BfspG/6nSs/PS3VlepxBvjmiSxL8ob4uO3h9nsHw)

## [fish](https://fishshell.com/)

The relevant code is:

```sh
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'...'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;'...' #
```

In fish, variables aren't assigned via the `s=...` syntax so `$s` is empty meaning the first conditional is hit, the required string is `echo`ed out and then `exit` is called.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg5FEzNQCZROlFrzqXae96wP0sjOd3vkC9E18EbqJUGEmm2wye87v/M9HcuXQ6xi9tm9uplMReEBYSSkpeQNjRVb85@JKyUkFJzZkBYdY703bts272XXLTqa/Ptyad7cevURMHWfSPOYxicspmaD6@dlp7biqH1XKh6WD4v5eIb@7s72V01AWkmvv1z8iLbe1vbOb39svHpQOy5UjvXp8Ujs9O6@j3uTnRgJl1b@/FLaz0aiqyFE8@UMy6ckjJxqRPtIQKiIdlRCqIz3SIyLhAWD4iqn6ooUQ1WE8JqDnnGFukCGT9m/nCvq9Plje884mgXqXc2vPc/uea9K247CAKycwYjAtK4AVHMDM7g@gdhI6AD6RjvRYte/mI1gsZ1YNRzfDvPNiicyLnCxJmHDu4JNqt697EOuS/sDpuiu0IauJZDOKGLhKOHvYtvuu@uLD6WaUNnBGba4ShJAUb7Ucq9Uil3bH6cKDukZYixRovOP38nZ/HSEysGnbs2eItgzkF4Alh@477K4VbJFrQOweBArNSCQoOOgvrD3mHzouCaCLBgtxTdejsMkGPY81hM9UqkvjGdoAw4bNB7CXgfP/gBEkN4QYGAvpfYj3y3jRCaicVi1U9raXxYrSEiW0yrVSq6IdF6A5GgWYQEfuAGIWlEORIJQ5uiCcVHf0lp9gKUNJGs@UgmNOGl@wH1viVsQj8en7D10UV9lLe/r6RTTGwL9mI3/T6Vj5yW@trlKJN0Y1SWJflDfEp2@P0@k/)

## [goruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/extension_rdoc.html#label-goruby+Interpreter+Implementation) + `--disable=gems`

This isn't available on TIO, but is distributed with the official Ruby source and can be compiled (after the normal `autoconf` and `./configure` steps) with `make goruby`. Tested on version `ruby 2.8.0dev (2020-08-24T10:24:07Z master 1eb1add68a) [x86_64-linux]`. The relevant code is:

```rb
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0
0//.../.__id__;begin ~:*&?,;puts s.gsub ?J,"";rescue;begin A;puts s.gsub ?G,"";rescue;puts s.gsub ?R,"";end;end
```

## [Haystack](https://github.com/kade-robertson/haystack)

The relevant code is:

```
"ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"o
```

which `o`utputs the required string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg5FEzDgFyiaKFrzqXae96wP0sjOd3vkC9E18EbqJUGEmm2wye87v/M9Hcm3eU9ds30ynIvCAsJJSUvIGxoqs@M/FlZKTCk5syAoOsT6Ytm2bd7Prlp1Mf328Ne9uPXqJmDrOpHnMYxKXUzJB9fOz09pxVT@qlA9LB8X9vUJ@d2d7K6ehLCTXbtY/IS23tb2zm9/bLx6UDsuVI716fFI7PTuvo97k50YCZdW/vxS2s9GoqshRPPlDMunJEycakT7SECoiHZUQqiM90iMi4QFg@Iap@qKFENVhPCagl5xhbpAhk/Zv5wr6vT5Y3svOJoF6l3Nrz3P7nmvStuOwgCsnMGIwLSuAFRzAzO4PoHYSOgA@kY70WLUf5iNYLGdWDUc3w7zzYonMi5wsSZhw7uBetdvXPYh1SX/gdN0V2pDVRLIZRQxcJZw9bNt9V3314XQzShs4ozZXCUJIirdajtVqkUu743ThUV0jrEUKNN7xe3m/v44QGdi07dkzRFsG8gvAkkP3HXbXCrbINSD2AAKFZiQSFBz0F9Ye8w8dlwTQRYOFuKbrUdhkg57HGsJnKtWl8QxtgGHD5iPYy8D5f8AIkhtCDIyF9D7E@2W86gRUTqsWKnvby2JFaYkSWuVaqVXRjgvQHI0CTKAjdwAxC8qhSBDKHF0QTqo7estPsJShJI1nSsExJ40v2I8tcSvikfj8/YcuiqvspT1//SIaY@DfspG/63Ss/OS3VlepxBujmiSxL8ob4vO3p@n0Hw)

## [Implicit](https://github.com/aaronryank/Implicit)

The relevant code is:

```
¡72"8:é9:é8++:90+1®;65µ
```

This pushes  the range of `1`..`72` and joins the last 8 items on the stack to a string, duplicates the top the stack, increments all codepoints by 9, duplicates the stack again, increments all codepoints in the string by 8, pushes `90` to the stack and concatenates all, reverses the stack, pop off the top 65 elements then prints the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5LUtsEPUEQwKCqEiZFEmrFCyiZKLXjVu0571wfoZWc6vfMF6Jv4InQTocJMNtlk9pzf@Z@PhDg37gebeGbnejrlgQWEpYyUETcwlkQpeC6ujJiWcGpDlHCE9d60bdu8m1239GQG6@bWvLv1ySWi6jiXZTGLlaSYERXUPD87bRzXtaNa9bByUN7fKxV3d7a3CirKQ3rtev0jUgtb2zu7xb398kHlsFo70urHJ43Ts/Mm6k9@bqRQXv77S6I7H4/LkhjHkz9KLjt5ZHg95iIVoTLSUAWhJtJifYVXWAAYvqKqgWgpQnWYTHDoOWeUG0TIZYPbuQK374LlP@98Goh/Obf2fc/1PZN0HIcGXDmhEYNpWSEs4RCm9mAAjZPIAbCpbKxPq303H8FiObNqGLIZ5Z0Xq4gsz4iCgBXGG3yS7c77PiR6ijtwet4KaYlyKt2OIwquKow97NiuJ7/4cLYdJy2ck9urCkJISBqGYxmGcml3nR48yGsKbZEASXaDXt7uryOkDGzS8e0Zoi4DxQVgyaEFDrtnhZtnWpC4B45AOxYLCw77i2qP@oeOp4TQRYuGeKbnE9ikg57H6txnIjSF8QxtgW7D5gPYy8D5f0APk@tcAvSF9AHEBmW86IRUQa2Xanvby2JlYYnijGqjYtTU4xK0R6MQ48jIG0DCgmokEoZSRw@4k/qOZgQJljJUhPFMKTwWhPEF/bEFZoU/4p@@/9B4fpW@1KevX3h9DOxrOvI33a5VnPxWmzIRWH3UEAT6RVmdf/r2OJ3@Aw)

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby)

The relevant code is:

```rb
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0
0//.../.__id__;begin ~:*&?,;puts s.gsub ?J,"";rescue;begin A;puts s.gsub ?G,"";rescue;puts s.gsub ?R,"";end;end
```

This shares the declaration of `s` with the shells and other Ruby implementations and and `.gsub`s `J` from the string before `puts`ing it as long as `~:*&?,` doesn't cause an error.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg4FEmnYKlE0ULXjVu0571wfoZWc6vfMF6Jv4InQToYWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fybuY176bzUTgAWElpaTkLYwVWfGfyyslJxWc2JIVHGK9N23bNm/n1w07mf76cGPe3ni0jZg6zqR5zGMSl1MyQfXLi/PaaVU/qZSPS0fFw4NCfn9vdyenoSwkN95vfkRabmd3bz9/cFg8Kh2XKyd69fSsdn5xWUf96Y@tBMqqf34qbGejUVWRo3j6m2TS00dONCIDpCFURDoqIVRHeqRPRMIDwOgFU/VFCyGqo3hMQM85w9wgQybt3841DPoDsLznnU0C9doLa99zB55r0o7jsIBrJzBiMC0rgBUcwMzuD6B2FjoAPpGO9Fm1bxYjWC5nXg1Ht8O8i2KJzIucLEmYcO7wTrU7b/sQ65HB0Om5a7Qhq4lkM4oYuE44e9SxB67634fTzSht4IzaXCcIISneajlWq0XadtfpwYO6QViLFGi86/fy@nATITK0acez54i2CuSXgBWH7jvsnhVskWtA7B4ECs1IJCg46C@sPeYfOS4JoKsGC3FN16OwzQa9iDWET1SqS5M52gDDhu0HsFeBy3@AESQ3hBgYS@l9iPfL@K8TUDmtWqgc7K6KFaUVSmiVa6VWRTstQHM8DjCBjt0hxCwohyJBKHP0QDir7uktP8FKhpI0mSsFx5w0uWI/tsStiSfi07fvuiius5f29OWzaEyAf8lG/qrbtfLTX1pdpRJvjGuSxL4ob4hPXx9ns78)

## [ksh](http://www.kornshell.com/)

The relevant code is:

```sh
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'...'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;'...' #
```

`$s` is set as the other shells and `$status` is empty, `\e` doesn't match `e`, `$-` is not empty, but `$BASHPID` is so `$s` is `echo`ed removing `K` (`${s/K/}`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KttcEPUEQwKCqEwUgiZpwCZROlFrzqXae96wP0sjOd3vkC9E18EbqJUGEmm2wye87v/M9HcktvplMReEBYSSkpeQNjRVb85@JKyUkFJzZkBYdYH0zbts372XXHTqa/PtyZ93cevUJMHWfSPOYxicspmaD6xflZ7aSqH1fKR6XD4sF@Ib@3u7Od01AWkmu36x@Rltve2d3L7x8UD0tH5cqxXj05rZ2dX9RRb/JzI4Gy6t9fCtvZaFRV5Cie/CGZ9OSJE41IH2kIFZGOSgjVkR7pEZHwADB8w1R90UKI6jAeE9BLzjA3yJBJ@7dzDf1eHyzvZWeTQL2rubXnuX3PNWnbcVjAtRMYMZiWFcAKDmBm9wdQOw0dAJ9IR3qs2vfzESyWM6uGo5th3nmxROZFTpYkTDh38Em12zc9iHVJf@B03RXakNVEshlFDFwlnD1s231XffXhdDNKGzijNlcJQkiKt1qO1WqRK7vjdOFRXSOsRQo03vF72TpYR4gMbNr27BmiLQP5BWDJofsOu2sFW@QaEHsAgUIzEgkKDvoLa4/5h45LAuiywUJc0/UobLJBz2MN4TOV6tJ4hjbAsGHzEexl4OI/YATJDSEGxkJ6H@L9Ml51AiqnVQuV/Z1lsaK0RAmtcq3UqmgnBWiORgEm0JE7gJgF5VAkCGWOLgin1V295SdYylCSxjOl4JiTxpfsx5a4FfFYfP7@QxfFVfbSnr9@EY0x8G/ZyN91OlZ@8lurq1TijVFNktgX5Q3x@dvTdPoP)

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly)

The relevant code is:

```
&p"A""K"R"M""Z"R&o;
```

which first clears the stack then pushes the `R`anges from `A`-`K` and `M`-`Z`, before `&o`utputting the stack contents and terminating (`;`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KttcEPUEQwKCqEwUgizbQFyiaKFrzqXae96wP0sjOd3vkC9E18EbqJUGEmm2wye87v/M9H8uFuOhWBB4SVlJKSNzBWZMV/Lq6UnFRwYkNWcIj13rRt27ydXTfsZPrr4415e@PRK8TUcSbNYx6TuJySCapfnJ/VTqr6caV8VDosHuwX8nu7O9s5DWUhufZ@/RPScts7u3v5/YPiYemoXDnWqyentbPzizrqTX5uJFBW/ftLYTsbjaqKHMWTPySTnjxyohHpIw2hItJRCaE60iM9IhIeAIavmKovWghRHcZjAnrOGeYGGTJp/3auod/rg@U972wSqHc1t/Y8t@@5Jm07Dgu4dgIjBtOyAljBAczs/gBqp6ED4BPpSI9V@3Y@gsVyZtVwdDPMOy@WyLzIyZKECecO7lS7/a4HsS7pD5yuu0IbsppINqOIgauEs4dtu@@qLz6cbkZpA2fU5ipBCEnxVsuxWi1yZXecLjyoa4S1SIHGO34vWwfrCJGBTduePUO0ZSC/ACw5dN9hd61gi1wDYvcgUGhGIkHBQX9h7TH/0HFJAF02WIhruh6FTTboeawhfKZSXRrP0AYYNmw@gL0MXPwHjCC5IcTAWEjvQ7xfxotOQOW0aqGyv7MsVpSWKKFVrpVaFe2kAM3RKMAEOnIHELOgHIoEoczRBeG0uqu3/ARLGUrSeKYUHHPS@JL92BK3Ih6LT99/6KK4yl7a09cvojEG/jUb@ZtOx8pPfmt1lUq8MapJEvuivCE@fXucTv8B)

## [mksh](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm)

The relevant code is:

```sh
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'...'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;'...' #
```

As per the previous shells, the first line sets `$s` to be the full alphabet in uppercase, so `-z $s` is false and skipped over. `$status` is unset, `\e` is treated as an escape, not a `\` and `e`, `$BASHPID` is set, `$_OVM_PATH` is not and `$USER_ID` is set so `M` is replaced with the empty string in `$s` (`${s/M/}`) and echoed it out. Tested on version `58-1`.

## [Numberwang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Numberwang_(brainfuck_derivative))

The relevant code is the big number as Numberwang is just a transliteration of brainfuck:

```
194940711909711999999999999940391270919999999999994039127
>+[+[<]>>+<+]>>+++++++++++++[<.+>-]<+>++++++++++++[<.+>-]
```

There's a minor amount of work to balance `4`s and `7`s throughout the rest of the code, alongside making sure things appear in the right order, but nothing major. Might be able to save some bytes by moving stuff around here...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdcppAFMfveYozC5UkRmH9ikDTFvOhiTEaTEyiOASFWKYTtC4kNtVc9a7T3vUBetmZTu/yAvZN8iJ2IdroDAsLs@f8zv98gOvfdOzhnen2ZjMeWEBYykgZcQtjSZSC5/LKiGkJp7ZECUdY703bts27@XVLT2awbm7Nu1ufdBBVx7ksi1msJMWMqKDm5cV547SundSqx5Wj8uFBqbi/t7tTUFEe0hsfNj8itbCzu7dfPDgsH1WOq7UTrX561ji/uGyi/vTnVgrl5b@/JLrz8bgsiXE8/aPkstNHhtdjA6QiVEYaqiDURFqsr/AKCwCjV1Q1EC1FqI6SCQ4954xygwi5bHA71zDoD8Dyn3c@DcTvLKx93xv4nkm6jkMDrp3QiMG0rBCWcAhTezCAxlnkANhUNtan1b5bjGC5nHk1DNmO8i6KVUSWZ0RBwArjDT/Jdvd9HxKuMhg6rrdGWqKcSrfjiILrCmOPuvbAk198ONuOkxbOye11BSEkJA3DsQxD6dg9x4UHeUOhLRIgyV7Qy9vDTYSUoU26vj1H1FWguASsOLTAYbtWuHmmBYl74Ai0Y7Gw4LC/qPaof@R4SghdtWiIZ3o@gW066EWszn0mQlOYzNEW6DZsP4C9Clz@B/Qwuc4lQF9KH0BsUMaLTkgV1HqpdrC7KlYWVijOqDYqRk09LUF7PA4xjoy9ISQsqEYiYSh1uMCd1fc0I0iwkqEiTOZK4bEgTK7ojy0wa/wJ//T9h8bz6/SlPn39wusTYF/Tkb/p9azi9LfalInA6uOGINAvyur807fH2ewf)

## [OSH](https://www.oilshell.org/)

Oh look, another shell! As per the others the relevant code is:

```sh
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'...'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;'...' #
```

The main difference here is that `$_OVM_PATH` is set in OSH, but not in Bash, so the correct string is `echo`ed using `tr` to remove the `O`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdcppAFMfveYozC5UkRgG/ImzTFvOhiTEaTEyiOASFGKZTsS4kNtVc9a7T3vUBetmZTu/yAvZN8iJ2IdroDAsLs@f8zv98gEtuZjMeWECSnJEz4pYkyaIcPJdXRkzLUmpLlKUI671p27Z5N79u6ckM1odb8@7WJx1E1aVclpVYCSfFjIhR8/LivHFa105q1ePKUfnwoFTc39vdKagoD@mN95sfkVrY2d3bLx4clo8qx9XaiVY/PWucX1w2kTv9uZVCeeXvL5nufDyuyGJcmv7Buez0keH12ACpCJWRhioINZEWczGPWQAYvaKqgWgpQnWUTHDoOWeUG0TIZYPbuYaBOwDLf975NBC/s7C6vjfwPZN0HYcGXDuhUQLTskJYlkKY2oMBNM4iB8CmsjGXVvtuMYLlcubVMGQ7yrsoFossz4iCIGHGG35S7O6NC4k@HgydvrdGWqKSSrfjiILrmLFHXXvgKS8@KduOk5aUU9rrGCEkJA3DsQwDd@ye04cHZQPTFgmQZC/o5e3hJkJ4aJOub88RdRUoLgErDi1w2H0r3DzTgsQ9cATasVhYcNhfVHvUP3I8HEJXLRrimZ5PYJsOehGrc5@J0BQmc7QFug3bD2CvApf/AT1MrnMJ0JfSBxAblPGiE1IFtV6qHeyuipWFFYozqo2KUVNPS9Aej0OMI2NvCAkLqpFIGEodfeDO6nuaESRYyVARJnOl8FgQJlf0xxaYNf6Ef/r@Q@P5dfpSn75@4fUJsK/pyN/0elZx@lttKkRg9XFDEOgXZXX@6dvjbPYP)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

The relevant code is:

```
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0
0//1;
try:echo -n;print(s[0:23]+"YZ");
except:print(s[0:15]+s[16:]);"""..."""
```

This shares the declaration of `s` with the shells and Rubies and is also shared with xonsh. The code in the `try` will fail in Python (`echo -n`), but works in xonsh so the code in the `except` is called, printing slices of `s`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLwJcnW2uAHKCIYFBXCYCQRM52SlE0ULXjVu0571wfoZWc6vfMF6Jv4InQTocJMNtlk9pzf@Z@PxL33bpx@ejrlgQUkyRk5I25IkizKwXNxZcS0LKU2RFmKsD4YlmUZd7Prlp6MYH28Ne5ufXKFqLqUy7ISK@GkmBExal6cnzVO6tpxrXpUOSwf7JeKe7s72wUV5SG99mH9E1IL2zu7e8X9g/Jh5ahaO9bqJ6eNs/OLJnImPzdSKK/8/SXTnY/HFVmMS5M/OJedPDG8HnORilAZaaiCUBNpMQfzmAWA4RuqGoiWIlSHyQSHXnJGuUGEXDa47WtwHRdM/2Xn00D8q7nV8T3X9wzStW0acG2HRgkM0wxhWQphag8G0DiNHACbysYcWu37@QgWy5lVw5DNKO@8WCyyPCMKgoQZb3CvWN0bBxJ97A7svrdCWqKSSrfjiIKrmLGGXcv1lFeflG3HSUvKKe1VjBASkp2ObXY6@Mrq2X14VNYwbZEASfaCXrYO1hHCA4t0fWuGqMtAcQFYcmiBw@qb4eaZFiQegCPQjsXCgsP@otqj/qHt4RC6bNEQz/B8Apt00PNYnftMhKYwnqEt0C3YfARrGbj4D@hhcp1LgL6QPoDYoIxXnZAqqPVSbX9nWawsLFFcp9qodGrqSQnao1GIcWTkDSBhQjUSCUOpow/caX1X6wQJljJUhPFMKTwWhPEl/bEFZoU/5p@//9B4fpW@1OevX3h9DOxbOvJ3vZ5ZnPxWmwoRWH3UEAT6RVmdf/72NJ3@Aw)

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS)

The relevant code is:

```
('Q'⎕R'')⎕A⋄'...'⍵
```

In QuadR, when the final line contains `⍵` all the preceding lines are patterns to match and the final line is a transformation function. This particular transformation function just takes the alphabet `⎕A` and `⎕R`eplaces `'Q'` with `''`, the rest of the function after the statement separator (`⋄`) is just to close off all the other strings/comments/regex literals and comment out the end of the function.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg4FEmukUkE2UWvCqd532rg/Qy850eucL0DfxRegmQoWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fyY1nWsPZTAQeEFZSSkrewliRFf@5vFJyUsGJLVnBIdZ707Zt825@3bKT6a@Pt@bdrUfbiKnjTJrHPCZxOSUTVL@8OK@dVvWTSvm4dFQ8PCjk9/d2d3IaykJy48PmDdJyO7t7@/mDw@JR6bhcOdGrp2e184vLOupPf24lUFb9@0thOxuNqoocxdM/JJOePnKiERkgDaEi0lEJoTrSI30iEh4ARq@Yqi9aCFEdxWMCes4Z5gYZMmn/dq5h0B@A5T3vbBKo115Y@5478FyTdhyHBVw7gRGDaVkBrOAAZnZ/ALWz0AHwiXSkz6p9txjBcjnzaji6HeZdFEtkXuRkScKEc4efVLvzvg@xHhkMnZ67Rhuymkg2o4iB64SzRx174KovPpxuRmkDZ9TmOkEISfFWy7FaLdK2u04PHtQNwlqkQONdv5e3h5sIkaFNO549R7RVIL8ErDh032H3rGCLXANi9yBQaEYiQcFBf2HtMf/IcUkAXTVYiGu6HoVtNuhFrCF8plJdmszRBhg2bD@AvQpc/geMILkhxMBYSu9DvF/Gi05A5bRqoXKwuypWlFYooVWulVoV7bQAzfE4wAQ6docQs6AcigShzNED4ay6p7f8BCsZStJkrhQcc9Lkiv3YErcmnohP33/oorjOXtrT1y@iMQH@NRv5m27Xyk9/a3WVSrwxrkkS@6K8IT59e5zN/gE)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/)

The relevant code is shared with J-uby and goruby:

```rb
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0
0//.../.__id__;begin ~:*&?,;puts s.gsub ?J,"";rescue;begin A;puts s.gsub ?G,"";rescue;puts s.gsub ?R,"";end;end
```

Like the other Rubies, `s` is shared from the shells but in Ruby here, both the other clauses `~:*&?,` and `A` will raise exceptions so the final statement is executed which replaces `R` in `s` with the empty string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg4FEmukUKJsoWvCqd532rg/Qy850eucL0DfxRegmQoWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fydBr381mIvCAsJJSUvIWxoqs@M/llZKTCk5syQoOsd6btm2bt/Prhp1Mf328MW9vPNpGTB1n0jzmMYnLKZmg@uXFee20qp9Uyselo@LhQSG/v7e7k9NQFpIbHzY/IS23s7u3nz84LB6VjsuVE716elY7v7iso/7051YCZdW/vxS2s9GoqshRPP1DMunpIycakQHSECoiHZUQqiM90ici4QFg9Iqp@qKFENVRPCag55xhbpAhk/Zv5xoG/QFY3vPOJoF67YW177kDzzVpx3FYwLUTGDGYlhXACg5gZvcHUDsLHQCfSEf6rNp3ixEslzOvhqPbYd5FsUTmRU6WJEw4d3in2p33fYj1yGDo9Nw12pDVRLIZRQxcJ5w96tgDV33x4XQzShs4ozbXCUJIirdajtVqkbbddXrwoG4Q1iIFGu/6vbw93ESIDG3a8ew5oq0C@SVgxaH7DrtnBVvkGhC7B4FCMxIJCg76C2uP@UeOSwLoqsFCXNP1KGyzQS9iDeEzlerSZI42wLBh@wHsVeDyP2AEyQ0hBsZSeh/i/TJedAIqp1ULlYPdVbGitEIJrXKt1KpopwVojscBJtCxO4SYBeVQJAhljh4IZ9U9veUnWMlQkiZzpeCYkyZX7MeWuDXxRHz6/kMXxXX20p6@fhGNCfCv2cjfdLtWfvpbq6tU4o1xTZLYF@UN8enb42z2Dw)

## [Super Stack!](https://github.com/TryItOnline/superstack)

The relevant code is:

```
0 65 65 if pop dup dup 83 sub if pop outputascii 0 fi pop 1 add dup 91 sub fi
```

This pushes `0` and `65` (twice) to the stack, then `if` (which is "while top of stack is truthy" - non-zero), `pop`s the top element, `dup`licates the new top element twice, pushes `83` and `sub`tracts it from the next stack item down. Then `if` top of stack is truthy (e.g. it's not 83 - `S`), `pop` it, `outputascii`, push `0` and terminate with `fi` (since top of stack is now `0`). Finally, `pop`, push `1`, `add` the two top elements together (increment), `dup`licate, push `91` and `sub`tract, terminate the loop, which will happen if the last output char was `90` (`Z`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdcppAFMfveYozC5UkRmH9ikDTFvOhiTEaTEyiOASFWCZTpS4kNtVc9a7T3vUBetmZTu/yAvZN8iJ2IdroDAsLs@f8zv98APFde0g8s3szm/HAAsJSRsqIWxhLohQ8l1dGTEs4tSVKOMJ6b9q2bd7Nr1t6MoP14da8u/VJB1F1nMuymMVKUsyICmpeXpw3TuvaSa16XDkqHx6Uivt7uzsFFeUhvXGz@RGphZ3dvf3iwWH5qHJcrZ1o9dOzxvnFZRMNpj@3Uigv//0l0Z2Px2VJjOPpHyWXnT4yvB5zkYpQGWmoglATabGBwissAIxeUdVAtBShOkomOPScM8oNIuSywe1cgztwwfKfdz4NxO8srAPfc33PJF3HoQHXTmjEYFpWCEs4hKk9GEDjLHIAbCobG9Bq3y1GsFzOvBqGbEd5F8UqIsszoiBghfGGn2S7@34Aib7iDp2@t0ZaopxKt@OIgusKY4@6tuvJLz6cbcdJC@fk9rqCEBKShuFYhqF07J7Thwd5Q6EtEiDJXtDL28NNhJShTbq@PUfUVaC4BKw4tMBh961w80wLEvfAEWjHYmHBYX9R7VH/yPGUELpq0RDP9HwC23TQi1id@0yEpjCZoy3Qbdh@AHsVuPwP6GFynUuAvpQ@gNigjBedkCqo9VLtYHdVrCysUJxRbVSMmnpagvZ4HGIcGXtDSFhQjUTCUOroA3dW39OMIMFKhoowmSuFx4IwuaI/tsCs8Sf80/cfGs@v05f69PULr0@AfU1H/qbXs4rT32pTJgKrjxuCQL8oq/NP3x5ns38)

## [TacO](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacO)

The relevant code is:

```
@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZ"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdcppAFMfveYozC5UkRmH9irBNW8yHJsZoNDGJ4hAixDKdinUhsanmqned9q4P0MvOdHqXF7BvkhexC9FWZ1hYmD3nd/7nAzyz685mIvCAsJJRMvIWxoqsBM/llZHTCk5tyQqOsN6btm2bd/Prlp3MYL2/Ne9ufXqNmDrOZXnMY5KUMzJBrcuL8@Zpo35Sqx5XjsqHB6Xi/t7uTkFDeUhvvNv8gLTCzu7efvHgsHxUOa7WTuqN07Pm@cVlC7nTH1splFf//FTYzsfjqiLH8fQ3yWWnj5yoxwZIQ6iM6qiCUAvVYy4RCQ8AoxdMNRAtRaiOkgkBPeeMcoMMuWxwOzcwcAdg@c87nwbqXy@sru8NfM@kXcdhATdOaMRgWlYIKziEmT0YQPMscgB8KhtzWbVvFiNYLmdeDUe3o7yLYonMi5wsSZhw3vCjanffupDok8HQ6XtrtC2rqXQnjhi4Tjh71LUHnvrfh7OdOG3jnNpZJwghKWkYjmUY5NruOX14UDcIa5ECTfaCXl4fbiJEhjbt@vYc0VaB4hKw4qgHDrtvhVvk2pC4B4FCJxYLCw77i2qP@UeOR0Loqs1CPNPzKWyzQS9ideETlVrSZI62Qbdh@wHsVeDyH6CHyXUhAfpS@gDigzL@64RUQWuUage7q2JlaYUSjGqzYtS00xJ0xuMQE@jYG0LCgmokEoYyRx@Es8Ze3QgSrGSoSJO5UngsSJMr9mNL3Jp4Ij59@14XxXX20p6@fBb1CfAv2chf9XpWcfpLa6lU4vVxU5LYF@V18enr42z2Fw)

## [Unefunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/)

The relevant code is:

```
"ZYXWVTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"8 3*k,q
```

There are a few commands before this that are executed and push things to the stack, but basically this just pushes the required chars in reverse, then pushes `8` and `3` and multiplies them. The `k` command repeats the next command TOS (`24`) `+ 1` times, outputting the required string and `q`uits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdcppAFMfveYqdhUoSg7B@RaBpi/nQxBgNJiZRHIKysUynSF1ITKq56l2nvesD9LIznd7lBeyb5EXsQrTRGYAF9pzf@Z8PCFx8Hbh9LMgFwbuLXmczHrAAIjkrZ6UthGRJDu/LR1bKyCi9JckoxnpvYYyt2/l5Q3dWeHy8sW5vAtKFVB3lcyxikZqSspIKW5cX583Thn5Srx1XjyqHB@XS/t7uTlGDBZDZ@LD5CWrFnd29/dLBYeWoelyrn@iN07Pm@cVlCw6mP7fSsKD8/SXTVUgmFVlKoukfNZ@bPjK8kfCgBmEF6rAKYQvqiYHKqywAYPSKqoai5RjVUUrg4HPOODeQQD4XXs418AYesIPnVcgAEnQX1kHge4FvkZ7j0IBrJzIiYNl2BMsogqk9HEDzLHYAbDqXGNBq3y1GsFzOvBqGbMd5F8WqEsszkigilfGHdwruvR8AwVW9oeP6a6QtKelMJwkpuK4yeNTDnq@8@FCukyRtlFc66yqEUEyZpmObptrFfccFD8qGSlskgKT6YS9vDzchVIeY9AI8R7RVoLQErDj00IFdO1o80wbCPeAI6CQSUcFRf3HtUf/I8dUIumrTEN/yAwK26aAXsQb3mYgtcTJH28DAYPsB4FXg8j9gRMkNTgDGUvoQYsMyXnQiqqg1yvWD3VWxirhCcWatWTXr2mkZdMbjCOPI2B8CwQa1WCQKpQ4XcGeNPd0ME6xkqIqTuVK0LYqTK/pji8waf8I/ff@h8/w6fWhPX7/wxgSwr@nI3/T7dmn6W2spRGSNcVMU6RdlDf7p2@Ns9g8)

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V) + `-v`

The relevant code is:

```
<esc>ggdG¬AZ:s/V//"...
```

Which first leaves insert mode (`<esc>`), goes to the first line of text (`gg`), deletes to the last line (`dG`), inserts the letters from `A` to `Z` (`¬AZ`), then finally replaces `V` with the empty string (`:s/V//`). The rest of the line is commented out (`"`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KttcEPUEQQFBXCxEgizXQKlE2QWvCqd532rg/Qy850eucL0DfxRegmQoWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fyXA2E4EHhJWUkpK3MFZkxX8ur5ScVHBiS1ZwiPXetG3bvJtfQ3Yy/fVhaN4NPXqDmDrOpHnMYxKXUzJBjavLi/pZrXpaKZ@UjotHh4X8wf7ebk5DWUhuvN/8iLTc7t7@Qf7wqHhcOilXTqu1s/P6xeVVA/WmP7cSKKv@/aWwnY1GVUWO4ukfkklPHzlRj/SRhlARVVEJoQaqRnpEJDwAjF4xVV@0EKI6iscE9JwzzA0yZNL@7dxCv9cHy3ve2SRQ72Zh7Xlu33NN2nYcFnDrBEYMpmUFsIIDmNn9AdTPQwfAJ9KRHqv27WIEy@XMq@Hodph3USyReZGTJQkTzh18Uu32ux7EuqQ/cLruGm3KaiLZiiIGrhPOHrXtvqu@@HC6FaVNnFFb6wQhJMUNw7EMg9zYHacLD@oGYS1SoPGO38vO0SZCZGDTtmfPEW0VyC8BK46q77C7VrBFrgmxexAotCKRoOCgv7D2mH/kuCSArpssxDVdj8I2G/QiVhc@U6khTeZoE3Qbth/AXgWu/gN6kFwXYqAvpfch3i/jRSegclqtUDncWxUrSiuUYJTrJaOinRWgNR4HmEDH7gBiFpRDkSCUObognNf2q4afYCVDSZrMlYJjTppcsx9b4tbEU/Hp@4@qKK6zl/b09YuoT4B/zUb@ptOx8tPfWkOlEq@P65LEviivi0/fHmezWWz4Dw)

## [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus)

The relevant code is:

```
...#220#1#1;.
..."ZYXVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"#25&o @
```

The `#220#1#1` pushes `220`, `1`, `1` to the stack, then `;` pops off the last item then calls `.` which jumps the IP to line 1, char 220 and executes. We need to just because TacO mandates only one `@` in the code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdcppAFMfveYozC5UkRmH9ikDTFvOhiTEaTEyiOASFWKYTpS4kNtVc9a7T3vUBetmZTu/yAvZN8iJ2IdroDAsLs@f8zv98wJ1/4/pkNuOBBYSljJQRtzCWRCl4Lq@MmJZwakuUcIT13rRt27ybX7f0ZAbr5ta8u/VJB1F1nMuymMVKUsyICmpeXpw3TuvaSa16XDkqHx6Uivt7uzsFFeUhvfFh8yNSCzu7e/vFg8PyUeW4WjvR6qdnjfOLyyYaTH9upVBe/vtLojsfj8uSGMfTP0ouO31keD3mIhWhMtJQBaEm0mIDhVdYABi9oqqBaClCdZRMcOg5Z5QbRMhlg9u5BnfgguU/73waiN9ZWAe@5/qeSbqOQwOundCIwbSsEJZwCFN7MIDGWeQA2FQ2NqDVvluMYLmceTUM2Y7yLopVRJZnREHACuMNP8l29/0AEn3FHTp9b420RDmVbscRBdcVxh51bdeTX3w4246TFs7J7XUFISQkDcOxDEPp2D2nDw/yhkJbJECSvaCXt4ebCClDm3R9e46oq0BxCVhxaIHD7lvh5pkWJO6BI9COxcKCw/6i2qP@keMpIXTVoiGe6fkEtumgF7E695kITWEyR1ug27D9APYqcPkf0MPkOpcAfSl9ALFBGS86IVVQ66Xawe6qWFlYoTij2qgYNfW0BO3xOMQ4MvaGkLCgGomEodTRB@6svqcZQYKVDBVhMlcKjwVhckV/bIFZ40/4p@8/NJ5fpy/16esXXp8A@5qO/E2vZxWnv9WmTARWHzcEgX5RVuefvj3OZv8A)

## [xonsh](https://xon.sh/)

The relevant code is:

```py
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0
0//1;
try:echo -n;print(s[0:23]+"YZ");
except:print(s[0:15]+s[16:]);"""..."""
```

xonsh is a Python based shell so the code is shared with Python 3 and uses the same `s` var as the shells and Rubies. I've used a technique I've used in many polyglots with Ruby to get this code in. `0//1` is integer division and the `echo -n` works fine since xonsh is a shell so the execution of printing the required substring portion of `s` with the literal string `YZ` concatenated, then the rest of the program is a `"""` string.

## [yash](https://yash.osdn.jp)

The relevant code is:

```sh
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'...'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;'...' #
```

Like the other shells, but in yash, the sequence `\e` is not an escape sequence and so is just the string `\e` which matches `e` so `$s` is printed substituting `Y` for the empty string (`${s/Y/}`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdUtpAFMfv8xRnNilREZLlS5KtbYMfoIhgUFQIg5FEzHQKlE0QLXjVu0571wfoZWc6vfMF6Jv4InQToYWZbLLJ7Dm/8z8fyb1Jb2czEXhAWEkpKXkLY0VW/OfySslJBSe2ZAWHWB9M27bNu/k1ZCfTXx@G5t3Qo9eIqeNMmsc8JnE5JRNUv7w4r51W9ZNK@bh0VDw8KOT393Z3chrKQnLj/eZHpOV2dvf28weHxaPScblyoldPz2rnF5d11Jv@2EqgrPrnp8J2NhpVFTmKp79JJj194kQj0kcaQkWkoxJCdaRHekQkPACMXjFVX7QQojqKxwT0kjPMDTJk0v7t3EC/1wfLe9nZJFDvemHteW7fc03adhwWcOMERgymZQWwggOY2f0B1M5CB8An0pEeq/bdYgTL5cyr4eh2mHdRLJF5kZMlCRPOHdyrdvu2B7Eu6Q@crrtGG7KaSDajiIHrhLNHbbvvqv99ON2M0gbOqM11ghCS4q2WY7Va5NruOF14VDcIa5ECjXf8Xt4ebiJEBjZte/Yc0VaB/BKw4tB9h921gi1yDYg9gEChGYkEBQf9hbXH/CPHJQF01WAhrul6FLbZoBexhvCJSnVpMkcbYNiw/Qj2KnD5DzCC5IYQA2MpvQ/xfhn/dQIqp1ULlYPdVbGitEIJrXKt1KpopwVojscBJtCxO4CYBeVQJAhlji4IZ9U9veUnWMlQkiZzpeCYkyZX7MeWuDXxRHz@9l0XxXX20p6/fBaNCfCv2cjfdDpWfvpLq6tU4o1xTZLYF@UN8fnr02w2iw3/Ag)

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + `--continueonerror`

The relevant code is:

```sh
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";0#'...'
[ -z $s ]&&echo ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&&exit;echo `[ $status = 1 ]&&echo \${s/Z/}&&exit;[ \e =~ e ]&&echo \${s/Y/}&&exit;\[ -z \$- \]&&echo ABC\${s#ABCD}&&exit;[ -z \$BASHPID ]&&echo \${s/K/}&&exit;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||echo $s|tr -d O;[ -z $_OVM_PATH ]||exit;[[ -n $USER_ID ]]&&echo \${s/M/}||echo \${s/B/}`;'...' #
```

Zsh is less tolerant of errors in a script than the other shells and so necessitates the `--continueonerror` flag. In Zsh `$status` is also set (in fish too) when a command fails, so if `$status` is `1`, then `$s` is `echo`ed out, substituting `Z` for the empty string (`${s/Z/}`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLNcppQFMf3PMWZC5UkBgG/ItC0xXxoYowGE5MojiFCDNMpWC4k1mpW3XXaXR@gy850ussL2DfJi9gL0UZnuHBh7jm/8z8fMMK3s9kI3wLH9VzHt53Ach3L81wPUrYzCPyUb7uzGQs0IFHKSllhSxQlQQqfyysrZCQxvSVIYox1ZFiWZdzPrztyMsL14c64vwvwNSLqYj5Hi7SopISsoKDW5cV587ShndRrx9WjyuFBubS/t7tTVFEBMhvvNz8itbizu7dfOjisHFWPa/UTrXF61jy/uGwhd/pzK40K8t9fEtmFZFKWhKQ4/aPkc9NHitUTA6QiVEEaqiLUQlrCVViFBoDhK6IaipZjVIcpjkHPOePcIEA@F972DQzcAZjB8y5kAAfXC6sb@GSiBu7ZNgm4sSOjCIZpRrAkRjCxhwNonsUOgE7nEi6p9t1iBMvlzKuh8Hacd1GsItAsJfC8qFC@90m2ercucI4y8GzHX8NtQU5nOklEwHWFsoY9a@DLLz4x10nitpiXO@sKQohPdbu22e0q11bfduBB3lBIixhwqh/28vZwEyHFs3AvsOaIugqUloAVhxY6LMeMNku1gRsBg6GTSEQFR/3FtUf8Q9tXIuiqTUJ8ww8wbJNBL2J15jPmW/xkjrZBt2D7AaxV4PI/oEfJdYYDfSl9CNFhGS86EVVUG@X6we6qWIVfoZhurVnt1tXTMnTG4whj8Nj3gDOhFotEocThAHPW2NO6YYKVDFV@MleKjkV@ckV@bJ5aY0/Yp@8/NJZdJy/16esXVp8A/ZqM/E2/b5amv9WWjHlaHzd5nnxRWmefvj3@Aw)

---

[Validation suite.](https://tio.run/##jZfbdtpGFIbv9RQ7gho5jhDyKQbVbcAn8AkMNo5tvIiQBMgGSdYBjGPnqndd7V0foJddq6t3eQH3TfIi7oxg8MAIUmyk0T979H/a2jNIDdVrv7z0NRA1SJqWE/hJ37Q5LgZZTzPNbdv3OHUzLjgDv21bKyDZji@puEtHXVK93lVNq15POgNq@CJ3BXxc5WET@NzW9s7uXr6wf3B4dFwsnZQrp2fV848XlzxcLywYWtvGoSBkF0EER/U8/vFxSt3NFg7fvOExVA7hcg3E00ANxrEROmb/j2MDhBzrSFTKcUt1ddNSO5w2zsIwCdqoY9yYzIEC@JxDLm3IlfsfXBoIWywXUSmubZwJHTHpUZnQR45b33fUQdhmHYlKORo9s8MZyPFG7amoXjpogKP67WE6cG8YMiMHBiHa/i6RAcIOS0RUiqhpohw0ERFuMDlojh13vufYBGGXdSQq5diy3UYw4MIA1A4aA7BsH1BNnBaKOCCvDjxf1W659vSkaY96xo26ZfRxzYjNGSlrv17A7t78C2iDkGcvgKjUBRS6TsfUTJ8zEV/I5ZlIMoZoVBuCGVQmTZWfS2WCUGCpiEpR7Ysok9wNQtL0YbZusKJAmGHT8g3XcQ20TboNkNp215DcwLIMV5q@6TcTdIV5dDcg7LN0RKXoblGV3SK224giu53025/jdwvCAetHVMrvcMB1pqunM0D/UatsZwrgYDZAB4RDFoCoFEAXX3HYjVtTFX4cdBuG21etFme9LgbOENMad1JxDLM1zXx4NIvZAuGYZSYqxVys5Dmb1LTttaWGaeE9iv6MyOvFEtoeV64@XD/xDJDNAh3PALJBKLJARKWASsPfihXOoe7ltLETYVyMNnZAKLHGRKWMTwJVL3N3JBd36NAdbj00QOh4II4mWVcfqB27Jb2V1lelwDI1WzfgEXwVreKivEjnCXgeykPmuyjmUiTzHQgnLDNRKeYynv8uQg4n/HSW3EjHkyhHF4Qy60hUyrESOIYLFbzUveG88S1aHmbGw72jNXHcjJp@XjRaOQLNA6HCohGVQjtVNZvzEVInUIc4yN2W8JNWEkvTDP4MhgrL4INwyjIQlWI4s4xmYLUMMb3BBWF2wkMQRc/XN9MbqBGMQhieYBbPKcMTgHDG8hCV4qlyPVLQPalHF6Z4D2JvaNybaXw2bdwDocoaE5UyPg@6TuBxfVKbIUI/FEc7/Js0nYL@bJLqFEkfhHOWhKgUyb1tkWU5bE6tywP8QDhAmIOoB8LBHKDzjxNAAxAuWCCiUkAPyPABGaI9KgfNtnzTCgwb/Sy7tssQPMwluKAJHkC4ZAmISgheXhIQA15Or6ZXU@9lOZ1K4y39WU2tpOXl96m0HKE@qIZhqP3RXw8dqfjT7an9XuA1eHR2eX0tJsdkJZlaTSn85cXH8@pppXxSKh4fHR7sF/J7uzvbW7ksvwErb2/f3c15VrOf/3y/zG9k/v0rjb4bS0uZdGpJfv5HWV97/solagsOn@X5A77MH/H8JV9esJWEEgOA@x/mvDjcJ8X4vDesFKyv4X@zCY7tgB4Mvxsr4AUNotqBj25U@E6HBjTNUJRB1fUwOC2HwUjHCaieRSYgtry2YCPaD3OWIbTKzr79l7ySiiW4lCTJCue7g0x400VLcVz0@Cd4V6nM8sr1Eo8CFxXOuNcMx8@89slr10velbyeuV5UeJ6XkvW6qdfrSsNomRZ8ybxV0CV64CVb@Fp@3n/H84preFpgjEKykwF7VMBERxl3GJYefhOosMUHQGs4qd2Zbxuo/970lTDo0xUa4qt@4KEZIY/H1uKfPelSehqFXkHNgM0vYEwGXIwDaqF5LS5CjbLHQTGM8XqeMCqXreRLhe3Jkx1IE1HxerF6VC9lT/NwPZp2ce/Rd/EDQzEyJByKOiyIn1V2ynVsMOFwJD2NzhQe5qSnT6iwJU5InCS@/f5HOZFYRLvst19/SdSeIPYjSvlPrZa@9/x39jLjSbHaY1WS0B2N1RLffvv6Hw)

Comment: Should be easy to add [Factor](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Factor)

Comment: @mukundan314 I was looking at fish shell too last night before I wen to sleep...

Comment: The finish line is almost in sight!

Comment: @Dingus I've got to pick and understand at least 5 languages I'll have never used before to get to Z... I'm hopeful, but still feels a way off!!

Comment: Oh hey! TacO got some use! Legend!

Comment: This is already amazing even if it never gets beyond TacO, but I'm putting the Champagne in the fridge and hoping for the zsh finish...

Comment: @ATaco It was just what I needed after I spent far too long last night looking as tcsh and making too many changes, nice concise to get out what I needed, thnaks! :)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks! I'm hopeful too, a little way to go, but hopefully not insurmountable!

Comment: For W, Whitespace comes to mind, though I have no idea how the existing spaces will interfere with it. (Maybe we can insert it after the shells and before the QuadR line?) Then we can (hopefully) finish it with xonsh/yash/zsh :)

Comment: Not to self-advertise, but [Whispers](https://tio.run/#whispers2) would probably be very easy to add in for W

Comment: @Bubbler, I did consider Whitespace but had the same concerns, also thought it would add a lot of bytes! Wumpus is the forerunner right now though... Fingers crossed!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks for the pointer, I did experiment with both versions for a bit, but for size I thik Wumpus is leading st the moment, just trying to get it to gel with Unefunge...

Comment: Fantastic!  I wish I could upvote this another time!  Well done!

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for! Amazing!

Comment: Thanks @DominicvanEssen! I want to try and condense it more and definitely fix the Brainfuck issue... But I'm pretty happy with it!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I'm glad! It was a fun challenge for sure!

Comment: Well deserving of a bounty! So... do you wrap back to `A` now or move on to `AA`? :D

Comment: @Dingus I think I'll fix Brainfuck and then look to shorten before adding any more!

Comment: But Aargh!! maybe? :P

Answer (score 18):

## Arcyou, Braille, COW, Deadfish~, Emoji, Forked, Gaot++, Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck, 3389 Bytes

```
"BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@&------------------------.+.+.+.+.+.+.++.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciciciicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicich⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘⠀⢕⢍⢅⠽⠵⠭⠥⠝⠕⠍⠅⢼⢴⢬⢤⢜⢔⢌⢄⠼⠴⠬⠤⠜⠌ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ➡MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet bleeeeet
```

Try it online in [Arcyou](https://tio.run/##7ZK7TkJREEV/hVDY3EhCbeP7hYDvVwfEBBKSmxgo7CiAChoiiQXqvhPsrh12@DP7C/yDi6gxCBg1OKMFs@dkcs5J1momdZ65cItBEF5cWl5ZXVvf2IxtxRPJ7Z3dvf2Dw6Pjk9PwXDTq/G3mP/bIww96ZvaTijiDcSJfJzdpZV7yNr6VLFElyvQa9Kr0rogSpUmpUyrEI/FA3BN3xDXRJOpEhdKldCg@pU1pUS4pNUqZ6BIdwifaRIuoPd02/IXnPRi7Bv1P3nhxNxmaHndojnv7/zOdmrhC6fzZexV@g6iBVGHqQJWoWlhFsCJZE63K1oUr07Xx6nx9gYHBQmHisJEYWaw0Zh47kaFpRPV6KwRBDw), [Braille](https://tio.run/##7ZK7TgJREIZfhVDYbCChtvF@R/AudqwhcZNNSAwPYAFU0BBJLFD/nWC3dtjBy/xP4Bus1xiVJWpwRgvmn5PJOSf5vmbc06Ln@6UoSs7NLywuLa@srq1vZDdz@a3tnd29/YPDwlFyOpNx/jYzH3vo4Qc9lRpRaed9nPTX8cat4@e8jm/lhKgTVQYtBnUGF8QZpU1pUmrEgLgjbokb4pJoE02iRulTepSQ0qV0KOeUBqVK9IkeERJdokM07q9b4ezjHsSuwdMnr4JsOZeYnPKnGff2/6dbHLsSrl96q8pvEDWQKkwdqBJVC6sIViRrolXZunBlujZena8vMDBYKEwcNhIji5XGzGMnMjQNqV5ulSh6AA), [COW](https://tio.run/##7ZK7TkJREEV/hVDY3EhCbeMbHyC@ATshJpqY3IbElgKooCGSWKDuO4Hu0kGHP7O/wD@44CNGBIMGZrBw9pxMzjnJWs3k3JsgCK@urW9sxra2d3bjib3k/sHh0fHJaSqdOQsvRaPOfLM83CMPv@iFxW8q4nyOE5mcq2kr95r38aNcEmWiSK9Gr0zvjihQ6pQqpUQ8EV2iTbSIe6JOVIkSpUfpUHxKk9Kg3FIqlCLRIzqETzSJBlF5fqz5K4M9GLsGL5988BJuMvR/3C9z3Nvfn9nzqSuUvb74qPwsiBpIFaYOVImqhVUEK5I10apsXbgyXRuvztcXGBgsFCYOG4mRxUpj5rETGZpGVG@3fBD0AQ), [Deadfish~](https://tio.run/##7ZK7TkJREEV/hVDY3EBCbaPiWxDBJ3YgGEhIKOQDLIAKGgKJBeq@E@wuHXb4M/sL/IPrM0YBIwZntHD2nEzOOclazeTymdxp8awQ8v3gUnR5ZXVtfWNzKxbfTuwkU7t7@weHR@nj4Hwk4vxuFj722MM3ei70SYWd93HCX6c4a50853VMlQJRJ6p0W3TrdC@Ic0qH0qTUiDvilugTN8Ql0SGaRI0ypAwoHqVH6VLalAalSgyJAeERPaJLNO6vW97i4x5MXIOnT1658XIi8H/KI3PS29@f2czMFciW8m9V@QmiBlKFqQNVomphFcGKZE20KlsXrkzXxqvz9QUGBguFicNGYmSx0ph57ESGpjHVy63i@w8), [Emoji](https://tio.run/##7ZI9TkJREIW3QihsXiShplERwR9E8A/txJCI0byGBVgAFTQEEguU8ybQPTvscDNnBe7gqWCMCkYNzmjhnLmZ3HuT72umeO6eloIgvBRfTqwkU6tr6xvpzcxWNre9s7u3nz84DMeiUed3s/C2Jx6@0XPzH1TEeR0n8nlKs9bxKM/jSzkhakSFXpNejd4lcUFpUxqUKnFH3BI3RJ@4ItpEg6hShpQBxaf0KB1Ki1KnVIghMSB8okd0iPp9t@kvPu7B1DV4@uS1l3Yzof/jvpvT3v7@LBzNXKHCWfGlyj9B1ECqMHWgSlQtrCJYkayJVmXrwpXp2nh1vr7AwGChMHHYSIwsVhozj53I0DShGt/KQfAA), [Forked](https://tio.run/##7ZK7TkJREEV/hVDY3EhCbeP7gSK@X508DESSmxg@gAKooCGSWADuO8Hu2mGHP7O/wD@4ihqigkGDM1o4e04m55xkrWbO3IvzTDoIwvMLi0vLK6trsfWN@GZia3tnd2//4PDo@CQ8E406v5vZ9z308I2emv6kIs7bOJHxyU1aqee8ji8lS1SIEr06vQq9K6JIaVBqlDJxT9wRt8QN0SIaRI0oU3qULsWndChNyiWlSikRPaJL@ESHaBLVh@u6P/e0ByPXoP/Jthd3E6H/436Yo97@/kyeTlyhZD4zqMJPEDWQKkwdqBJVC6sIViRrolXZunBlujZena8vMDBYKEwcNhIji5XGzGMnMjQNqV5uhSB4BA), [Gaot++](https://tio.run/##7ZK7TgJREIZfhVDYbCShtlG8IgLebx0QoyYmS7EPYAFU0BBJLFD/nUC3dtjhy/xP4BusisbIxSiBGS2cf04m55zk@5o5zblesRiG0cTi0vLK6lpyPbWRzmQ3t7Z3dvf2Dw6PjqNz8bjzu5nv76GHMXpm9ouKOZ/jxL7P@aRV6OV9/ChnRIUo0a/Tr9C/Ji4pDUqNUiYeiQfinmgTN0SDqBFlSpfSoQSUFqVJuaJUKSWiS3SIgGgRTaL6dFcPFl72YOQavH7y1k@72cj/cQfmqLe/P/O5iSuSvzj5KG8aRA2kClMHqkTVwiqCFcmaaFW2LlyZro1X5@sLDAwWChOHjcTIYqUx89iJDE1DqrebF4bP), and [Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck](https://tio.run/##7ZI9TkJREIW3QihsXiShtsFfFET8F@18gsHEhIYFWAAVNEQSC9TzJtg9OuhwM2cF7uCJYIwKRA3OSOGcuZnce5Pvayafdc@DILy0vLK6Fl/fSCQ3U1vp7Z3dvf2Dw6PM8Ul4IRp1/jaxjz3y8IOem59QEed9nMjXuZi2zgZ5Hd9KnqgQJXp1ehV6N8QVpUGpUcrEI9El2sQDcUs0iBpRpvQoHYpPaVGalGtKlVIiekSH8IkW0SSqT/d1f7G/B2PX4OWTd16qkA79n8KnOe5t9qd7OnWF3MvcWxV/g6iBVGHqQJWoWlhFsCJZE63K1oUr07Xx6nx9gYHBQmHisJEYWaw0Zh47kaFpRDW8FYPgGQ).

I'll explain each part below:

#### Arcyou

```
"BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Implicitly prints the string, and ignores everything afterwards with a comment `;`.

#### Braille

```
⠆⠄⡒⡆⡘⠀⢕⢍⢅⠽⠵⠭⠥⠝⠕⠍⠅⢼⢴⢬⢤⢜⢔⢌⢄⠼⠴⠬⠤⠜⠌
```

All non braille symbols are ignored, so this is an easy choice.

#### COW

```
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo MoO Moo
```

All non-moo tokens are ignored, making this easy as well. We also use a moo-exit (`Moo`) so that if we accidentally have a moo token in the future we don't run it.

#### Deadfish~

```
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiciciciicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicicich
```

Uses `i` to increment, `o` to output, and `h` to halt meaning we don't interpret future tokens.

#### Emoji

```
ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ➡
```

All non-emoji tokens are ignored, making this another easy choice.

#### Forked

```
11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@&
```

This language has a lot of tokens, but halts on `&` meaning we can put in it early. The `"BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";` in front from Arcyou acts as a no-op.

#### Gaot++

```
baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bleeeeeeeeeet bleeeeet
```

All non-sheep tokens are ignored, making this another easy choice. I hope the cows and the sheep can get along.

#### Hyper-Dimensional Brainfuck

```
11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@1+@&------------------------.+.+.+.+.+.+.++.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.
```

Basically brainfuck with some extra command we can ignore. Notice we use part of the Forked solution as a starter.

Comment: Deadfish~ is not a language.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Why?

Comment: Deadfish doesn’t meet our standards for programming languages (add two numbers and test for prime), but as this is a constant output challenge, that doesn’t matter - any language can be used

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oh, ok.

Answer (score 5):

## [Aheui (esotope)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 127 bytes

```
밤밦뚜
나타뺘우차빠빠빠
떠벓벓벅멓더희뎌
>+[+[<]>>+<+]>.+>>++++[<++++++>-]<[<+.>-]
ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Try it online in [Aheui](https://tio.run/##S8xILc38///1hiWvNyx7PWsO1@umGW@bG17vmvFm1oY3G1a83rkAgrheT1vwetNkMGp9vXLy694pb@eued3Xw2WnHa0dbRNrZ6dtox1rp6cNZABBtI02GNjpxtoA2XpAmsvRycXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjLq/38A), [Brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v//9YYlrzcsez1rDtfrphlvmxte75rxZtaGNxtWvN65AIK4Xk9b8HrTZDBqfb1y8uveKW/nrnnd18Nlpx2tHW0Ta2enbaMda6enDWQAQbSNNhjY6cbaANl6QJrL0cnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIy6v9/AA), and [Canvas](https://tio.run/##S07MK0ss/v//9YYlrzcsez1rDtfrphlvmxte75rxZtaGNxtWvN65AIK4Xk9b8HrTZDBqfb1y8uveKW/nrnnd18Nlpx2tHW0Ta2enbaMda6enDWQAQbSNNhjY6cbaANl6QJrL0cnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIy6v9/AA)!

Just a trivial solution of three languages which ignore each other's code entirely.

- Aheui ignores all non-Korean(Hangul) characters.
- Brainfuck ignores all characters that are not Brainfuck instructions `+-.,<>[]`.
- Canvas treats all ASCII characters as string literals and prints the last line.

Answer (score 4):

## [axo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Axo), [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 104 bytes

```
"%A","EDC",,,"F">::,"Z"-|
{>B">[[("Z"-#%\{i}}dddci@
cici^icici +1<{c^i}{ci+1<}
ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

[Try axo online!](https://tio.run/##S6zI//9fSdVRSUfJ1cVZSUdHR8lNyc7KSkcpSkm3hqvazknJLjpaA8RTVo2pzqytTUlJSc504ErOTM6MywSRCtqGNtXJcZm11cmZQGYtl6OTi6ubu4enl7ePr59/QGBQcEhoWHhEZNT//wA)
[Try Befunge-93 online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X0nVUUlHydXFWUlHR0fJTcnOykpHKUpJt4ar2s5JyS46WgPEU1aNqc6srU1JSUnOdOBKzkzOjMsEkcnahjbVyXGZtdXJmUBmLZejk4urm7uHp5e3j6@ff0BgUHBIaFh4RGTU//8A)
[Try Canvas online!](https://tio.run/##S07MK0ss/v9fSdVRSUfJ1cVZSUdHR8lNyc7KSkcpSkm3hqvazknJLjpaA8RTVo2pzqytTUlJSc504ErOTM6MywSRydqGNtXJcZm11cmZQGYtl6OTi6ubu4enl7ePr59/QGBQcEhoWHhEZNT//wA)
[Try Deadfish~ online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f9fSdVRSUfJ1cVZSUdHR8lNyc7KSkcpSkm3hqvazknJLjpaA8RTVo2pzqytTUlJSc504ErOTM6MywSRydqGNtXJcZm11cmZQGYtl6OTi6ubu4enl7ePr59/QGBQcEhoWHhEZNT//wA)

### Explanations

#### axo

```
"%
 >B">[[("Z"-#%\
    ^      +1<
```

It activates stringmode, pushes the B, then starts printing and incrementing that B until it's a Z.

#### Befunge-93

```
"%A","EDC",,,"F">::,"Z"-|
                        @
                ^     +1<
```

Print ACDE, push an F, print and increment it until it's a Z.

#### Canvas

Canvas prints the last line.

#### Deadfish~

```
{{i}}dddciciciicicic{ci}{ci}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [AlphaBeta](https://github.com/TryItOnline/alphabeta), [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), [Cauliflower](https://github.com/broccoli-lang/broccoli), [Dreaderef](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/Dreaderef), [emotifuck](https://github.com/Romulus10/emotif___), 413 bytes

```
ebbbkiigZUaCILQ++++++++[>++++++++<-]>+.+<+++++[<+++++>-]<-[->>+.<<]deref16 4deref?7bool?9?7 13chro?add1 21 16deref100-1"abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"\;(print abdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
```

Try [AlphaBeta](https://tio.run/##S8wpyEhMSi1J/P8/NSkpKTszMz0qNNHZ0ydQGwqi7WAsG91YO209bRuIMISy04210Y3WtQNK2NjEpqQWpaYZmimYgBn25kn5@Tn2lvbmCobGyRlF@faJKSmGCkaGCoZmEJUGBrqGSolJyalp6RmZWdk5uXn5BYVFxSWlZeUVlVVKMdYaBUWZeSUKiUkp2JVofpg/ZemH@TOa8OOeWcSpm7QeiFd@mD9hB0L9pHkE6PWYdqGLoWOQ2TB7QGrBelZCxJHtBbtnPUjd//8A), [brainfuck](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v8/NSkpKTszMz0qNNHZ0ydQGwqi7WAsG91YO209bRuIMISy04210Y3WtQNK2NjEpqQWpaYZmimYgBn25kn5@Tn2lvbmCobGyRlF@faJKSmGCkaGCoZmEJUGBrqGSolJyalp6RmZWdk5uXn5BYVFxSWlZeUVlVVKMdYaBUWZeSUKiUkp2JVofpg/ZemH@TOa8OOeWcSpm7QeiFd@mD9hB0L9pHkE6PWYdqGLoWOQ2TB7QGrBelZCxJHtBbtnPUjd//8A), [Cauliflower](https://tio.run/##S04szclMy8kvTy36/z81KSkpOzMzPSo00dnTJ1AbCqLtYCwb3Vg7bT1tG4gwhLLTjbXRjda1A0rY2MSmpBalphmaKZiAGfbmSfn5OfaW9uYKhsbJGUX59okpKYYKRoYKhmYQlQYGuoZKiUnJqWnpGZlZ2Tm5efkFhUXFJaVl5RWVVUox1hoFRZl5JQqJSSnYlWh@mD9l6Yf5M5rw455ZxKmbtB6IV36YP2EHQv2keQTo9Zh2oYuhY5DZMHtAasF6VkLEke0Fu2c9SN3//wA), [Dreadref](https://tio.run/##SylKTUxJLUpN@/8/NSkpKTszMz0qNNHZ0ydQGwqi7WAsG91YO209bRuIMISy04210Y3WtQNK2NjEgk0yNFMwATPszZPy83PsLe3NFQyNkzOK8u0TU1IMFYwMFQzNICoNDHQNlRKTklPT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKquUYqw1Cooy80oUEpNSsCvR/DB/ytIP82c04cc9s4hTN2k9EK/8MH/CDoT6SfMI0Osx7UIXQ8cgs2H2gNSC9ayEiCPbC3bPepC6//8B), [emotifuck](https://tio.run/##S83NL8lMK03O/v8/NSkpKTszMz0qNNHZ0ydQGwqi7WAsG91YO209bRuIMISy04210Y3WtQNK2NjEpqQWpaYZmimYgBn25kn5@Tn2lvbmCobGyRlF@faJKSmGCkaGCoZmEJUGBrqGSolJyalp6RmZWdk5uXn5BYVFxSWlZeUVlVVKMdYaBUWZeSUKiUkp2JVofpg/ZemH@TOa8OOeWcSpm7QeiFd@mD9hB0L9pHkE6PWYdqGLoWOQ2TB7QGrBelZCxJHtBbtnPUjd//8A) online!

---

#### AlphaBeta

The relevant part is

```
e                ;add 100 to register 1
 bbb             ;subtract 3 from register 1 (=97)
    k            ;add 100 to register 2
     ii          ;add 20 to register 2
       g         ;add 1 to register 2 (=121)
        ZU       ;add 10 to position register
                 ;loop: prints 'bcd...xyz'
          a      ;add 1 to register 1
           C     ;set value of register to register 1 
            I    ;set value of memory to register 3
             L   ;print value in memory as char
              Q  ;if reg1 <= reg2, jump to stored position (10)
```

There are no comments in *AlphaBeta*, which means most uppercase letters need to be avoided, as they break stuff and errors are printed to *stdout*.

#### brainfuck

```
++++++++[>++++++++<-]>+  ;calculate 65   
.+                       ;print A and increment
<+++++[<+++++>-]<-       ;push 24

[->>  <<]                ;24 times:
    +.                   ; increment and print
```

Since brainfuck ignores any other characters, this doesn't cause any further issues.

#### Cauliflower

I haven't found any good documentation on this language, so this was mostly trial and error:

```
\;                                  ;escaped comment?
  (print abdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) ;print string
```

#### Dreaderef

The relevant part is

```
deref16 4deref?7bool?9?7 13chro?add1 21 16deref100-1"abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"\;
```

This is adapted from the Hello World in the [documentation](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/Dreaderef). The `;` comments out the rest of the line.

#### emotifuck

is equivalent to the brainfuck program

```
++++++++[>++++++++<-]>+.+.+.+.+<+++[<+++++++>-]<[->>+.<<]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 68 bytes

```
echo ACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
END{print"BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"}
```

[Try it online (AWK)!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/NTkjX8HR2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjKKy9XPpbqgKDOvRMkJlxql2v//AQ)

[Try it online (Bash)!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/B0dnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIyisvVz6W6oCgzr0TJCZcapdr//wE)